# Why does my Record-triggered Flow Scheduled Path not show up in Time-Based Workflow query results?

Tags: visual-workflow, time-dependent-workflow

I built an after-save record-triggered flow on `Opportunity` using the Spring 21 Scheduled Path feature.  When testing the flow, I went to look at the UX under `Setup | Monitoring | Time-Based Workflow` and entered a simple filter:

```
Object equals Opportunity
```

No results returned as shown below. I'm sure the time-based action should have been scheduled. What gives?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike Workflow time-dependent actions where the query `Object equals Opportunity` would work, for some inexplicable reason, when using Flow Scheduled Paths ..

- Even though they are associated with a *record-triggered flow and the flow's object must be identified*
- The value of the Object field is not populated in the underlying object `WorkflowTimeQueue` (undocumented, unqueryable)

The proof of this was by changing the query to:

```
Automation Type equals Flow Scheduled Path
```

[image]

Other queries would work such as:

```
Created By                      equals "lastname, firstname"
Created Date                    equals todaysDateInYourLocale
Workflow, Flow or Process Name  equals yourFlowAPIName
```