# Time-based Workflow on Event End Date not firing

Tags: workflow, time-dependent-workflow

I want to send an email to a user when Event End Date is reached. I have created 2 TBWF rules, one triggering 0 Hours After "**Event End Date**" and another 0 Hours After "**Event End**", and neither is firing.

First off, anyone knows why there are 2 different fields for End Date in the Time Trigger dropdown?

[image: 2 Event End Dates]

Continuing on - the criteria for both rules is the same: on create or edit of Event, when Custom_Field = 'Scheduled'. I have tried the following combinations with no luck (gave each an hour to batch up and execute):

- create Event with Event End Date = 2 mins from now
- create Event with Event End Date = 1 hour from now
- edit Event with Event End Date = 2 mins from now and Custom_Field to 'Scheduled' (changed)

In every scenario the "Time-Based Workflow" report page shows no results:

[image: Time-Based Workflow results]

Anyone knows why these rules wouldn't be firing?

Comment: possibly related: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/339862/why-does-my-record-triggered-flow-scheduled-path-not-show-up-in-time-based-workf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I triggered the workflow again today (a few days after creating it) and with no explanation it showed up on the "Time-Based Workflow" page. It only ran for the workflow that had its timer on the "Event: End" field.

[image]

So, I guess that's the answer? Maybe sandboxes are delayed a little? I don't know what the delay is since I left it for a few days. Anyway, this kind of randomness is pretty standard in the Salesforce universe, so that's fine.