# Scheduled Path Not Running

Tags: visual-workflow, recordtriggeredflow, scheduled-flow

I have a fairly simple record triggered flow that runs when the specified object is created or updated. It has 2 paths, one immediate and one scheduled. The immediate path works perfectly, however the scheduled path never seems to fire.

For reference the scheduled path is supposed to fire 1 day before a specified date/time field on the record. This date/time field is a formula field that simply references a field on a related record. After checking the "FlowInterview" table for paused Flows in developer console, the interview doesn't appear as I would expect. A similar story is told when viewing the Time-Based Workflows, as it does not appear. I have also extensively debugged the flow and both paths seem to run flawlessly.

I'm sure there's something simple that I am overlooking, however if you have any ideas as to why this may be happening I would appreciate the help!

I'll leave images of the flow below to further convey my issue, however if there is other information that would be necessary or questions you may have feel free to reach out.

[image: Scheduled Flow]

Comment: _I have also extensively debugged the flow and both paths seem to run flawlessly_ and  _The immediate path works perfectly, however the scheduled path never seems to fire_ are contradictory statements.

Comment: In the first statement, I was referring to the built in flow debug tool provided by salesforce. I am able to debug the paths with the given tool and both the immediate and scheduled paths run without issue. I simply wanted to include this statement to affirm there are no inherent issues with the flow in and of itself. If there is anything else I can clear up, please let me know.

Comment: Please edit the question and include relevant portions of the debug log for the scheduled path

Comment: Related: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/419866/issue-with-scheduled-path-actions-time-based-flow-they-do-not-work

Comment: related: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/339862/why-does-my-record-triggered-flow-scheduled-path-not-show-up-in-time-based-workf