# Issue with scheduled path actions (time-based flow) - they do not work

Tags: scheduled-flow, scheduled-path

We are building custom logic to to unassign certain topic from a knowledge article on certain scheduled date which is a field on a knowledge article.

We tried to build a scheduled flow action for this but it is not working when run from schedule.

[image]

[image]

This is interesting that we can see records in Time Based Workflow, but when time comes to process those records, nothing happens and the logic is not performed.

We try to set the scheduled date to be on the next day.

We can see records on the next day disappear from the list, but the action is not executed for them.

We also struggle to find any logs from scheduled path execution, while we can easily find the log for immediate execution or execution when date field is set to today.

Is scheduled path run under the user who modified the record or by automated process user?

How scheduled path execution is different when set the value of date field not to today but to tomorrow or any future date?

How can we make it work? Should we use instead of this approach Scheduled Apex?

Answer (score 2):

I think we have figured out the culprit.

Our apex action wasn't bulkified and processed only the last record, and since we had many records we didn't notice only one record was processed.

When we set to current date, the record was processed instantly and only one record has been passed to the apex, so it was working fine.

The Scheduled Path executing runs under the user who modified the record or deployed the flow - in our case this was the same user.

So we had to setup Debug Log to catch this log.

Scheduled Paths are executed at midnight by Organization Default Time Zone, which was   `(GMT-07:00) Pacific Daylight Time (America/Los_Angeles)` for our case.

Midnight at LA is 9 a.m. (or 10a.m. during the summer time) in Ukraine, so we can see a log at 9:01 a.m. running through several records.