Record-Triggered Flow - Scheduled Path Didn't Work
I've set up a Record-Triggered Flow on the Case object that utilizes a Scheduled Path to update the status after a specified date/time field has passed.


This flow works perfectly in the Sandbox (Debuged and Tested), but I encountered an issue in Production where it did not trigger as expected.
Troubleshooting Steps Taken:
Verified the flow and its activation status in Production.
Checked for any differences in the environment settings between Sandbox and Production.
Ensured that the flow and field configurations are identical in both environments.
Questions:

Are there any known issues or limitations with Scheduled Paths in Record-Triggered Flows in Production?

How can I effectively debug or monitor scheduled actions in Production?


Additionally, I am unable to verify the scheduled actions using the time-based workflow queue.
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Debugging the flow: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/superbadges/superbadge_flow_debugging_sbu

your filters for the Time-Based Workflow screen may be incorrect; record-triggered flows with scheduled paths work just fine in prod

@cropredy, Filter I used :  Object equals [ Object Name] and
Workflow Rule, Flow, or Process Name equals [FLOW API NAME]

Sahil -- see https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/339862/why-does-my-record-triggered-flow-scheduled-path-not-show-up-in-time-based-workf - there are issues with Object
